# Cannot use HttpClient in a portable class library

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-store-apps, portable-class-library

I've installed Microsoft HTTP Client Lib via nugget but I cannot use the `HttpClient` class. It does not see the namespace `System.Net.Http`. I'm new to .net/microsoft platform. The project is based on the.net portable library.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You did not mentioned the actual error message. Are you sure you got the portable http client?

Comment: Yes, I've got the portable http client, but wasn't added via Add Reference... I've added it and works now (needed clean solution - rebuild)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the NuGet package, per project. That's the same as "Add Reference". Just installing it into one project does not make it accessible for all projects. It sounds like this was the issue, given that your screenshot is from Object browser.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem when I've added http client as a reference via add reference. I've thought that using .net portable lib will gave me access to all it's subsequent namespaces.